# How to force correct overload

Tags: .net

I have two methods, one takes object parameter the other takes a parameter of type `System.Web.UI.Page`. I'm sending a class that descends from `System.Web.UI.Page`, but the method that gets called is the one that takes the `object` parameter.

```
class Primitive
public object Resolve(object FromObject, Sources Source, string Expression)
{
}

public object Resolve(System.Web.UI.Page FromObject, Sources Source, string Expression)
{
}
}
```

I call it with web page i'm on, whose base class of its base class is `System.Web.UI.Page`.

But I call it from here:

```
public Data.CompoundData<Compound<P>, P, object> Resolve(object Source)
{
    Data.CompoundData<Compound<P>, P, object> functionReturnValue = default(Data.CompoundData<Compound<P>, P, object>);
    functionReturnValue = new Data.CompoundData<Compound<P>, P, object>(this);
    foreach (Primitive Primitive in this) {
        functionReturnValue.Add(Primitive.Resolve(Source, Primitive.Source, Primitive.SourceExpression));
    }
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

The fact that the variable used is of type `object` makes a difference. I don't want to have to over load this calling function also. What must I do to make this calling function call the correct overload?

NOTE: If I take away the overload that has the `object` signature, it works (as in the case of Page). But I need the `object` overload, which is a "catch all" overload for all other object types.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the base class is System.Web.UI.Page and not a different kind of page?

Comment: Did you try casting it to System.Web.UI.Page?

Comment: See my answer.  It worked from me withOUT casting.

Comment: @Blam I don't know enough about VB.Net, but does it work exactly the same as C# in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solves the problem without using a case or an if statement.

`GetMethod` does what I want here. It routes me to the right overload, and if there is no specific overload existing, then it routes me to the "catch all" object overload.

It has the advantage of not needing to be updated when additional types are used in more overloads; therefore, it should be easier to maintain.

Any performance penalty of using `Reflection` is nominal in my case because my loop will always have less than a dozen iterations.

```vb
Public Function Resolve(Source As Object) As Data.CompoundData(Of Compound(Of P), P, Object)
  Resolve = New Data.CompoundData(Of Compound(Of P), P, Object)(Me)
  For Each Primitive As Primitive In Me
    Dim MethodInfo As System.Reflection.MethodInfo = GetType(Primitive).GetMethod("Resolve", New Type() {Source.GetType, GetType(Primitive.Sources), GetType(String)})
    Resolve.Add(MethodInfo.Invoke(Primitive, New Object() {Source, Primitive.Source, Primitive.SourceExpression}))
  Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Show more code because this works for me

```
namespace WebApplicationOverload
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OverLoad1(new Object());
            OverLoad1(new Page());
            OverLoad1(new MyPage());  // this call OverLoad1(Page page)
            OverLoad1((Page)(new MyPage()));

        }
        public void OverLoad1(Object obj)
        { 
            if (obj is Page) OverLoad1((Page)obj);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Object");
        }
        public void OverLoad1(Page page)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Page"); 
        }
    }

    public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public MyPage() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: One that is not boxing.  Page is object.  Add one line to fix this.